# Python Replace Newlines with <br/>

Tags: python

I've perused the available threads and nothing worked. Tried [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54760909/1005607) with the double-slashes, it didn't work. Also tried the [raw-string approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11989578/1005607) as `r\n` and that didn't work either.

I need to replace all newlines (let's start with `\n`) to `<br/>`. See the following screenshots showing how the result doesn't change from the original string, which is `obj.get(key)`:

```
.replace('\\n', '<br/>')
.replace(r'\n', '<br/>')
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: If they're actually newline characters, don't use escapes or raw strings to make it a literal backslash followed by `'n'`, just do `.replace('\n', '<br/>')` to replace actual newlines.

Comment: Where did you call the `getWithHTMLBreaksForNewlinesOrTrimToNone()` function?

Comment: Thanks, `ShadowRanger`'s plain `\n` worked. However, when I wanted to include the multiple options `\r\n` it didn't work. I got into this situation by trying to include both `\r` and `\n`.

Comment: `'<br/>'.join(text.splitlines())`.

Comment: This isn't a proper duplicate - the other question wasn't really about how to do this, but about a problem with using `.replace`. This question is about a **different** problem with using `.replace`, which should probably be considered a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert the text to stream in order to call readlines, and replace the last character (carriage return by )

Like this

```
>>> msg = "Bob Smith\nJane Doe\nJane,\nPlease order more widgets\nThanks,\nBob\n"
>>> msg
'Bob Smith\nJane Doe\nJane,\nPlease order more widgets\nThanks,\nBob\n'
>>>
>>> import io
>>> buf = io.StringIO(msg)
>>> buf.readline()[-1]='<br>'
```

You need to iterate over buff